# ContentProposalAdapter prevent new line on select proposal

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I use the `ContentProposalAdapter` to provide content assist to my StyledText fields. I wrote an adapter that implements `IControlContentAdapter`, `IControlContentAdapter2` to support the StyledText. My problem is that, when I press return to insert the proposal the return key is inserted into the StyledText and after that the proposal is inserted.

Why are the `UP` and `DOWN` arrows not traversed, but the return key is.

How to prevent the return key from begin inserted into the StyledText field when used to select a proposal.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the question is old, but as I googled and this Post nearly covered my problem, but without a solution, I thought to provide my solution I found now.

My Problem was exactly the same but the newline got inserted after the selected proposal. 
Selecting the proposal via double click works just fine so I agreed with you that it´s probably the StyledTextWidget that gets notified about the Enter...
First I tried setPropagateKeys(false) on my ContentProposalAdapter, as the doc says it "indicates whether key events (including auto-activation characters) received by the content proposal popup should also be propagated to the adapted control when the proposal popup is open". But this does not work either.

What actually worked for me is the following: 
I added an VerifyKeyListener to the StyledTextWidget and just filtered the Enter Event when the ProposalPopup is open. I thought that maybe wouldn´t work as the newline gets inserted after the proposal but on my program it works fine so it seems the closure of the proposal popup is done after the Enter Key is passed to the StyledTextWidget.

Heres the code:

```
styledText.addVerifyKeyListener(new VerifyKeyListener() {

@Override
public void verifyKey(VerifyEvent arg0) {
        try {
            KeyStroke k = KeyStroke.getInstance("Enter");
            if(k.getNaturalKey() == arg0.keyCode &&  contentProposalAdapter.isProposalPopupOpen()) {
                arg0.doit = false;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you implement `IControlContentAdapter`, `IControlContentAdapter2` in your code. Did you try [this](http://rcp-company-uibindings.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/com.rcpcompany.uibindings/src/com/rcpcompany/uibindings/internal/uiAttributeFactories/contentAdapters/StyledTextContentAdapter.java)? I use that in my custom `StyledText` implementation. But all of them are `SWT.SINGLE` Text fields. I hope it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need the StyledText to be a SWT.MULTI. I tried you implementation but the effect is the same. I think the problem is inside the ContentProposalAdapter. To be more specific i think the TargetControlListener inside the ContentProposalAdapter is not able to suppress the return from being inserted.